# Currency formatting on vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,###,##0}" rendered="{!IF(attr.Name == 'Rate Card Item Price' || attr.Name == 'Sold Unit Price' || attr.Name == 'Price', true, false)}">
<apex:param value="{!attr.value}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

I want currency formatting and I am using above code but I am getting this error on vf page :

> The value attribute on  is not in a valid format. It
>   must be a positive number, and of type Number, Date, Time, or Choice

Please help on this.

Comment: How do you initialize attr ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works as well. The hashtags display numbers in that position if they exist. So it will display $3.14 instead of $000,003.14 as in the example using ${0, number, 000,000.00}

Comment: <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}"> works as well.